# Why is the previous result returned from my EF stored procedure function import?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, stored-procedures

3 programmer colleagues here are baffled by this. **Why is old data is being returned from a prior stored procedure call?** Here I show the incorrect result of the second search:

[image]

The first search works fine. I enter 7392, click the button and get stock 7392 results as expected. But if I enter a second number (7395) then the unwanted 7392 result is returned again.

I use EF database first with the designer. The stored procedure is wrapped by an Entity Framework function import (`usp_StockSearch`). Results go into an entity. Here is the code:

```
TofsData.TofsEntities context = mainWindow.TofsEntitiesContext;

ObjectResult<TofsData.StockSearchResult> stockSearchResults = 
                        context.usp_StockSearch(NewStockNumTextBox.Text);

List<TofsData.StockSearchResult> stockList = stockSearchResults.ToList();

StockSearchResultsListBox.ItemsSource = stockList;
```

As the program runs the function import results go into an `ObjectResult<t>` of my entity type (`StockSearchResult`). Calling `ToList()` on the ObjectResult runs the sproc and puts the returned database values in a `List<StockSearchResult>`.

Prior to running this code I see that stockList, stockSearchResults, and ListBox.ItemsSource are null and the ListBox.Items.Count is 0. When I step through the code I see the incorrect result after .ToList() executes.

When the stored procedure is run from SSMS it returns the expected results every time. I've run SQL Profiler to be sure the correct search parameter is passed to the SPROC.

If I run a search that returns multiple results I get back the expected results appended to the prior results. Any ideas of what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, As per your comment in the answer below, you solved this issue. Can you please guide me how you fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before when the context is a global variable that is only created when the parent class is constructed. Basically, it's an EF cache issue that I think gets fixed in 6.0 (which is sadly still in alpha).

I would try using a context-per-request pattern - it fixed a similar issue I had a few weeks ago.

Comment: That's probably it. My code is in a user control that pulls the context from a property of the parent main window. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @DeveloperDan FWIW, this might help explain the root problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/21/productivity-improvements-for-the-entity-framework.aspx - there's a paragraph about 1/4 of the way down that talks about model caching and how to turn it off.